# SSRS export format customizations and what are the limitations?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a 3rd party system a user uses which requires the user manually import new data when the user chooses.  I have a view in MS SQL server that has the fields in the exact order that is wanted.

This 3rd party system needs the export file in a comma quote format.  For this I want every single field surrounded with quotes and not just the ones that contain the field delimiter (a comma).

I have worked with the configuration files to try and customize how csv is exported.  It seems the available options for the CSV renderer does not allow me to get to this format.  I think?  Am I making this more difficult than I need to?  What do I need to do to get to a format like this?

Seeing as this report could be run without any parameters every time I am contemplating setting up a thing with Python, as I could accomplish exactly what I want in a very small number of lines of code.  However, it would be nice if I could use SSRS as it takes away my need to figure out the delivery of the export file and is also a simple enough interface any user should be able to figure out how to use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL is a data source, to get data out of.  Since you are simply looking for a way to extract data from the database, a python script to create the file exactly as you wish would be the simples explanation.  K.I.S.S.  :)